# Rails 6 ActiveStorage - test fixture_file_upload() not permitted in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to test my controller with uploading an image but in my integration test the param is never permitted. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'm using the latest Rails 6.0.2.1. Below is my test and what I have in my controller.

**Test**

```
test "should return error" do
  image = fixture_file_upload(file_fixture('avatar.jpg'), 'image/jpg')
  put organisation_images_path(@organiser), 
      params: { organiser: { avatar: image } },
      as: :json

  assert_response :success
end
```

**Controller**

```
def update
  if @organiser.update(org_params)
    render json: {url: url_for(@organiser.avatar)}
  else
    render json: {errors: @organiser.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private
def org_params
  params.require(:organiser).permit(:avatar)
end
```

**Params**

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"organiser"=><ActionController::Parameters {"avatar"=><ActionController::Parameters {"original_filename"=>"avatar.jpg", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007f8469065b40>", "content_type"=>"image/jpg"} permitted: false>} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"resources/images", "action"=>"update", "organisation_id"=>"123", "image"=>{"organiser"=>{"cover"=>{"original_filename"=>"avatar.jpg", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007f8469065b40>", "content_type"=>"image/jpg"}}}} permitted: false>
```

As you can see the `avatar` param is not permitted and this happens after I've called `org_params` for the first time.

Comment: Does this actually work if you send a JSON request in any other way? I would be surprised if fixture_file_upload worked as its intended for multipart forms.

Comment: I'm using javascript (StimulusJS) to send the params and using `Rails.ajax` to send the data with `dataType` set to `json`. The `data` is created via a `FormData()` object. How would you test this?

Comment: I'm guessing the content when you send the ajax request is actually form data and the content disposition is multipart which would explain why it would work. Sending files with JSON is actually pretty awkward as you have to base64 encode them. I'm not quite sure how to test this without a system test that runs js.

Comment: OK. thank you. I might do a integration test without the `as: :json` and then like you say use a system test so it runs the JS.